# How to compare two large data sets using hadoop mapreduce?

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am new to hadoop and mapreduce. We have a normal java application where we read a file ( 8 GB in size ) from hadoop file system and we apply some rules on that data. After applying rules we get java hashmap (which is huge in size)  and we keep that data in cache or in buffer. At the same time we get the data from hive by applying a query on it and prepare a java hashmap which is again huge in size. Now we compare both the hashmaps data to prepare final report to check the data accuracy.

In the above process since we are using normal java program to do the stuff we are facing below problems.

1. To process this huge data it takes ages to complete the job. Because input file contains tens of millions of records in it and we need to apply rules on each row to extract the data. It takes days to complete the job. At the same time hive also contains the same amount of data, query is taking too much time to return the data from hive.
2. Since we are keeping the data in buffer we are facing memory issues.

Now we are trying to implement the same in hadoop mapreduce.

1. What is the best way to achieve the above scenario?
2. What are the best ways to implement the above scenario in mapreduce?
3. How can I increase the application performance by using mapreduce?

Answer (score 3):

8 GB is a tiny data set. I can fit 4 of these 'data sets' into my Laptop RAM! Just dump it in a any relational engine and massage it as fit until the cows come home. This is not 'big data'.

For the record, the way to do processing of two truly large datasets (say +1 TB each) in Hive is a sort-merge-bucket join (aka. SMB join). Read [LanguageManual JoinOptimization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+JoinOptimization), watch [Join Strategies in Hive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB4H3Yt5VWM).